# Quisiera ver la imagen del slider según el número que número yo haga click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .sliderModalImage {
            height: 100vh;
            display: inline-flex;
            overflow: hidden;
            transform: translateX(0);
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
            cursor: grab;
        }

        .slide {
            max-height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 1rem;
            user-select: none;
        }

        .slide img {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 60%;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }

        .btn {
            background-color: #444;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        }

        .grabbing {
            cursor: grabbing;
        }

        .grabbing .slide img {
            transform: scale(0.9);
        }
        .contenedor {
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="contenedor" id="contenedor1">slide 1</h1>
    <h1 class="contenedor" id="contenedor2">slide 2</h1>
    <h1 class="contenedor" id="contenedor3">slide 3</h1>
    <div class="sliderModalImage" >
        <div class="slide" id="0">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584438784894-089d6a62b8fa?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8cGhvbmV8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide" id="1">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525598912003-663126343e1f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8cGhvbmV8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide" id="2">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534536281715-e28d76689b4d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fHBob25lfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.contenedor').on('click', function() {
                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('.contenedor').css('display', 'none');
                $('.contenedor').css('display', 'block');
            });
        });
        const slider = document.querySelector('.sliderModalImage'),
          slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'))

        let isDragging = false,
          startPos = 0,
          currentTranslate = 0,
          prevTranslate = 0,
          animationID = 0,
          currentIndex = 0

        slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
          const slideImage = slide.querySelector('img');
          console.log(slideImage);
          slideImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault());

          // Touch events
          slide.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart(index));
          slide.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);
          slide.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);

          // Mouse events
          slide.addEventListener('mousedown', touchStart(index));
          slide.addEventListener('mouseup', touchEnd);
          slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', touchEnd);
          slide.addEventListener('mousemove', touchMove);
        });

        window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          return false;
        }

        function touchStart(index) {
          return function (event) {
            currentIndex = index
            startPos = getPositionX(event);
            console.log(startPos);
            isDragging = true;
            animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animation);
            slider.classList.add('grabbing');
          }
        }

        function touchEnd() {
            isDragging = false
            cancelAnimationFrame(animationID);

            const movedBy = currentTranslate - prevTranslate;

            if (movedBy < -100 && currentIndex < slides.length - 1) currentIndex += 1

            if (movedBy > 100 && currentIndex > 0) currentIndex -= 1

            setPositionByIndex();

            slider.classList.remove('grabbing');
        }

        function touchMove(event) {
            if (isDragging) {
                const currentPosition = getPositionX(event);
                currentTranslate = prevTranslate + currentPosition - startPos;
            }
        }

        function getPositionX(event) {
            return event.type.includes('mouse') ? event.pageX : event.touches[0].clientX;
        }

        function animation() {
            setSliderPosition();
            if (isDragging) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
        }

        function setSliderPosition() {
            slider.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`;
        }

        function setPositionByIndex() {
            currentTranslate = currentIndex * -window.innerWidth;
            prevTranslate = currentTranslate;
            setSliderPosition();
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

No encuentro la manera de hacer que si yo hago click en el slider 2 se me despliegue el slider mostrando la imagen con id 2.

Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Lo siento no entiendi tu pregunta, quieres mostrar el slider dependiendo de que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas usar IDs, porque no coinciden los de contenedor con las imágenes. Es suficiente con usar el índice, porque es la misma cantidad de contenedores e imágenes.

En tu código, estabas usando *jQuery* solo para la función que se ejecuta al cargar la página, pero no es necesario, se puede lograr que el slider funcione con Javascript puro, solo necesitas recorrer los contenedores y asignar evento usando el índice para mostrar la imagen correspondiente.

```js
// Ejecutar cuando se haya cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Obtener contenedores y recorrer con su respectivo índice
    document.querySelectorAll('.contenedor').forEach((item, index) => {
        // Asignar evento para escuchar clics
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Usar índice del contenedor para actualizar el elemento a mostrar
            currentIndex = index;
            // Mostrar slider
            setPositionByIndex();
        });
    });
});

const slider = document.querySelector('.sliderModalImage'),
          slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'))

        let isDragging = false,
          startPos = 0,
          currentTranslate = 0,
          prevTranslate = 0,
          animationID = 0,
          currentIndex = 0

        slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
          const slideImage = slide.querySelector('img');
          // console.log(slideImage);
          slideImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault());

          // Touch events
          slide.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart(index));
          slide.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);
          slide.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);

          // Mouse events
          slide.addEventListener('mousedown', touchStart(index));
          slide.addEventListener('mouseup', touchEnd);
          slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', touchEnd);
          slide.addEventListener('mousemove', touchMove);
        });

        window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          return false;
        }

        function touchStart(index) {
          return function (event) {
            currentIndex = index
            startPos = getPositionX(event);
            console.log(startPos);
            isDragging = true;
            animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animation);
            slider.classList.add('grabbing');
          }
        }

        function touchEnd() {
            isDragging = false
            cancelAnimationFrame(animationID);

            const movedBy = currentTranslate - prevTranslate;

            if (movedBy < -100 && currentIndex < slides.length - 1) currentIndex += 1

            if (movedBy > 100 && currentIndex > 0) currentIndex -= 1

            setPositionByIndex();

            slider.classList.remove('grabbing');
        }

        function touchMove(event) {
            if (isDragging) {
                const currentPosition = getPositionX(event);
                currentTranslate = prevTranslate + currentPosition - startPos;
            }
        }

        function getPositionX(event) {
            return event.type.includes('mouse') ? event.pageX : event.touches[0].clientX;
        }

        function animation() {
            setSliderPosition();
            if (isDragging) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
        }

        function setSliderPosition() {
            slider.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`;
        }

        function setPositionByIndex() {
            currentTranslate = currentIndex * -window.innerWidth;
            prevTranslate = currentTranslate;
            setSliderPosition();
        }
```

```css
        .sliderModalImage {
            height: 100vh;
            display: inline-flex;
            overflow: hidden;
            transform: translateX(0);
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
            cursor: grab;
        }

        .slide {
            max-height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 1rem;
            user-select: none;
        }

        .slide img {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 60%;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }

        .btn {
            background-color: #444;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        }

        .grabbing {
            cursor: grabbing;
        }

        .grabbing .slide img {
            transform: scale(0.9);
        }
        .contenedor {
            align-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
    <h1 class="contenedor" id="contenedor1">slide 1</h1>
    <h1 class="contenedor" id="contenedor2">slide 2</h1>
    <h1 class="contenedor" id="contenedor3">slide 3</h1>
    <div class="sliderModalImage" >
        <div class="slide" id="0">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584438784894-089d6a62b8fa?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8cGhvbmV8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide" id="1">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525598912003-663126343e1f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8cGhvbmV8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide" id="2">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534536281715-e28d76689b4d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fHBob25lfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Era exactamente lo que necesitaba, muchísimas gracias.